# Commerce Server 2009 - For how long an anonymous user basket information is stored in the database before it is gone

Tags: e-commerce, microsoft-commerce-server

I have a question related to Commerce Server related to products basket.

Let's assume a situation when user A is an anonymous user that went all way through the shopping cart(chooses product, fills in information) then changes his mind on the last step(before submitting order), kills the browser and does something else. From what I know the basket info is stored in the database and Commerce Server uses a cookie that holds and ID that is a key for the basket in the database. If user A comes back to the same computer  opens the browser the basket will still be there.

I need to know for how long this users basket  stays in the database. Lets say after six month my customer wants to send him an email with a remainder that he forget to submit order. The email will have a link  pointing to the basket information that we retrieved from the database.

Our concern is for how long this anonymous user basket will stay in the database so our customer can use that information? Does it stays there forever or it is deleted after a certain period of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it will stay there forever.

As for abandoned basket emails, read up on what other people have tried, but for our clients we send these emails after a couple of days or a week max, definitely not after a few months. By that time the customer either doesn't want the product, or has bought it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I know 6 month or longer doesn't make much sense but is what they want. I just wanted to find out if the baskets will be in the database and wouldn't disappear after a certain period of time. And if they do what is the period exactly.
Thank you.

Comment: I can confirm that unless you have a process clearing old baskets out, they will indeed stay forever.